# REST API for setting multi select field type in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I have installed following plugin to support multi-value type field in Azure DevOps
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control#:~:text=Azure%20Devops%20Services,used%20to%20back%20the%20extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control#:%7E:text=Azure%20Devops%20Services,used%20to%20back%20the%20extension).

I am able to set the option for this field by separating using "semicolon". like "A; B; C"
I can also see this field in my work item and able to set the values.

I need help with how can I update this multivalue type field through REST API.
I want to change the value of the work item which has this multi-value type field through REST API. I have already tried updating them using the following approaches

1. "A; B"
2. "A, B"
3. "[A, B]"
4. "A;B"
5. "A,B"

It sets up the value which I am sending using option 4, but it adds those as an extra option though the option already exists with that value. I can see extra spaces on the option which I am sending through REST AP{I, but I have checked my JSON there is no extra space (using option 4).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add a new work item field `Multivalue control Test` and configure `Multivalue control`

We could get the work item details via the REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

And we could check the value of field `Custom.MultivaluecontrolTest`

Result:

[image]

Then we could update the value via the REST API [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-field) to update the value.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

Sample request body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Custom.MultivaluecontrolTest",
    "value": "A;B;C"
  }
]
```

Result:

[image]

The filed value format is `A;B;C`, same as UI

Comment: thanks for the answer. Have you checked the Azure DevOps work item after the update, is it not adding the one which you update using REST API as an extra option (with extra space), keeping the original one intact?

Comment: Hi @SachinSarawgi. Yes, I have tested it, we could update the filed via this REST API and it will not affect or change other fields.